# How to change the scroll behavior in a flexible item?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

In the current code snippet first flexible item ( i.e div element with class 'flex-item2') is shrunk based on the height of second flexible item to fit into the container.

1. Is there a way to restrict the red colored top div ( i.e first div element with class 'item1') from scrolling?
2. Another requirement is that I want the scroll bar only on the div which has content that exceeds the size. ( i.e second div element with class 'item1')

```css
.flex-container {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: lightgrey;
}

html, body
{
    margin: 0px; 
    width: 100%;
}

html
{
    height: 100vh;
}

body
{
    min-height: 100vh;
}

.item1 {
    background-color: cornflowerblue;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
.flex-item2 {
    background-color: red;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
.flex-item3 {
    background-color: green;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item2"><div style="background-color: red;"class="item1">flex item 1<br>flex item 1<br>flex item 1<br>flex item 1<br>flex item 1</div><div class="item1">flex item 2<br>flex item 2<br>flex item 2<br>flex item 2<br>flex item 2<br>flex item 2<br>flex item 2<br>flex item 2<br>flex item 2<br>flex item 2<br>flex item 2<br>flex item 2<br>flex item 2<br>flex item 2<br>flex item 2<br>flex item 2<br>flex item 2<br>flex item 2<br>flex item 2<br>flex item 2<br>flex item 2<br>flex item 2<br>flex item 2<br>flex item 2<br>flex item 2<br>flex item 2<br>flex item 2<br>flex item 2<br>flex item 2<br>flex item 2<br>flex item 2<br>flex item 2<br>flex item 2<br>flex item 2<br>flex item 2<br>flex item 2<br>flex item 2<br>flex item 2<br>flex item 2<br>flex item 2<br>flex item 2<br>flex item 2<br>flex item 2<br>flex item 2<br>flex item 2<br>flex item 2<br>flex item 2<br>flex item 2<br>flex item 2<br>flex item 2<br>flex item 2<br>flex item 2<br>flex item 2<br>flex item 2<br>flex item 2<br>flex item 2<br></div></div>
  <div class="flex-item3">flex item 3<br>flex item 3<br>flex item 3<br>flex item 3<br>flex item 3<br>flex item 3<br></div>  
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is this what you're after? (no changes to HTML; tested only on Chrome) https://jsfiddle.net/u3ro6czr/

Comment: Exactly... In the mean time I have also found an answer by making the first child as position absolute.. But your output works in chrome only where as making absolute works in edge and firefox also

Comment: Yeah, for my solution to work in FF and Edge the overflow element requires a defined height in order to trigger the scrollbar. https://jsfiddle.net/u3ro6czr/1/

Comment: But I do not want to define the height. The content should automatically take care. Anyways making absolute is working fine. Thank you..